# Configuring CUDA and OpenCV with Visual Studio on 64 bit machine

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, cuda, hpc

I have been trying to configure OpenCV2.1 and CUDA3.1 on Visual Studio 2008 on a 64bit Windows XP machine, since past 1 week. But all in vain.

OpenCV alone is working fine. CUDA3.1 alone is working fine as well.
I am using CUDA3.1 for 64 bit ... But for OpenCV, I am using 32 bit installation (as provided on Source Forge) - Possible Error ??

In a CUDA project when I configure OpenCV settings, and compile a sample project, I get error on following files:

cxcore.hpp
cxoperations.hpp
cxcore.hpp
cxmat.hpp
and also on CUDA build rules.

All the above files are not written by me; but are libraries (I guess).

Any directions to install CUDA, OpenCV over VS on a 64bit XP machine ?

Comment: Please post the errors which Visual Studio is reporting.  Did you compile a 64bit version of cmake to build the project files or did you just download the 32bit binaries?

Comment: I just used the Cmake's 32 bit binaries.. Then generated a VS solution ... Build that solution for x64 ... But the build is showing errors too.

Answer (score 3):

Libraries linked to your application should have been compiled to the same arch. You cannot mix architectures.

In other words, you must **compile everything** -- your app, OpenCV and CUDA -- **to be 32bit** (or 64 bits if you need).

My advice to you is compile CUDA for 32bits and then change the properties of your project to build your application to 32bits too (since you already have the 32bits version of OpenCV ).

**EDIT:**

For the linking problems:

```
unresolved external symbol _cufftExecR2C@12
unresolved external symbol _cufftExecC2R@12
unresolved external symbol _cufftPlan2d@16
unresolved external symbol _cufftDestroy@4
```

according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3824886/cuda-linking-error-visual-studio-2008), add this library to your project settings: **cufft.lib**

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to build Cmake's 64 bit libraries -- but I'm not certain.  You definitely need to build OpenCV in x64 to build native apps on a Win XP x64 install.  If the build of OpenCV is showing errors, then you'll need to solve those first before attempting to compile your app which links against the as of yet incorrectly compiled OpenCV libs.